# When is a true statement in any of the compact subsets of $X$ ALSO TRUE in the entire set $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, logic

I have a simple but important question in math:

When is a statement that is true "for all $x$ in any compact subsets $[a,b]$ of $\mathbb{R}$" ALSO TRUE FOR ALL $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Here's some cases.

1. It seems true that a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous on every compact subsets $[a,b$] is also continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. On the contrary, a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous on every compact subsets $[a,b]$ is **NOT** uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
3. It seems also true that if the solution $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}$ ($t \geq 0$) of an O.D.E. 
   \begin{equation}
   \dot x(t) = f(x(t)),\;\; \;x(0) = x_0
   \end{equation}
   exists and is unique for all $t \in [0, t_0]$ with arbitrary $t_0 \in (0,\infty)$, then it is also true for all $t \in [0, \infty)$ (this comes from the case of globally Lipschitz $f$).

In summary, there is some statement in $\mathbb{R}$ that is true globally if it is true for every compact subsets, but also some counter-example like uniform continuity in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is there some condition or technique that makes the true statement in every compact subsets also true globally?

And what happens in a general metric or topological space, where closed and bounded subsets are not necessarily compact?

Comment: Well every property that is local. For instance, the continuity is a local property, therefore it suffises to prove it on any compact. The *uniform continuity* is an example of a non-local property.
Your example **3** mainly comes down to the unicity of the solution on its interval, it doesn't really belong with the other examples.

Comment: I've also heard that continuity is a local property, but uniform continuity is a non-local (global?) property. However, I cannot still figure out exactly why they are identified like those. Can you explain a little bit about this?